# How can return structure array from a C++ dll to Java Applet using JNI?

Tags: java, c++, dll, applet, java-native-interface

I have a C++ dll class. I want to return a structure array to Java Applet by using a JNI method.
How can I access it from Java?

(structure array contains different type of structures)

Already returned a String array---

```
public native String[] fun();

JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_fun(JNIEnv* pEnv, jobject Pobj)
{
}
```

but I didn't know how to work with Structure Array.

Could anyone please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build the same structure as Java objects. Copy the values from the C++ structure into the Java structure in JNI. Return the Java structure and use it as normal Java objects.

Answer (score 0):

There are few good code examples from Sun at [Sun: STrings and Arrays](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jnistring.html#object)

Try it out and tell us of your progress.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [JavaCPP](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/), which generates all the nasty C++ JNI code for us. Then we only need to call `Pointer.position()` from Java to navigate native arrays of structures.